# create common header footer for all modules in yii2

Tags: model-view-controller, view, yii2, header, footer

I have built an application on Yii2 framework where it has the following structure

```
assets/
config/
controllers/
models/
modules/
   |
    -- module-1 
          |
           - controllers
           - models
           - views
               |
               - header.php
               - footer.php
    -- module-2 
          | 
          - controllers
          - models
          - views
              |
               - header.php
               - footer.php
views/
  |
  - layouts/
       |     
       - header.php
       - footer.php
       - main.php
web/
```

**My application has 3 modules in which 2 are built as modules & called so and 1 module uses Yii2's default controller,models,views structure & called so** but all the 3 has same header footer but located & called from 3 different places in the application as shown in the above structure. **If user wants to edit the header or footer he has to change the same code at 3 different places which is not a good practice what I want here is all the 3 module's has to share a common header footer.** I googled for a solution but didn't find right answer, I am a beginner to Yii framework. Can anyone please tell how to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the best way of dealing with shared views is to extract them to widget. It provides better encapsulation and it is much easier it extend it in the future (for example by adding some settings) than including views directly.

Create `FooterWidget` and `HeaderWidget` which renders your views, and call it in layouts:

```
<?= HeaderWidget::widget() ?>
```

And when you need settings:

```
<?= HeaderWidget::widget([
    'facebookUrl' => 'someURL',
]) ?>
```

Comment: Widgets are the best & easiest solution. You could also hook onto View events, beginBody and endBody (https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-views#view-events), attaching the same handler for all 3 modules or you could set up your own events.

Answer (score 1):

If you have different layouts in your module, but all of the layouts draw the same header and footer, you can use aliases in each of layout, to directly point to needed views.

```
<?php echo $this->render('@app/views/layouts/header'); ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo $this->render('@app/views/layouts/footer'); ?>
```

It's only in case if different layouts.. Otherwise @vishuB 's answer is fit

Comment: In views inside my modules I have included my header & footer with code like `include_once Yii::$app->getModule('module_name')->basePath.'/views/header.php';` so, in the place of this line I have simply replaced your code i.e., `echo $this->render('@app/views/layouts/header');` its working fine but while calling views we generally pass some data to the views so here I am also passing some data to the header so, the data is not getting passed to the header.

Comment: @prasadchinthala pass variables to view like this: `$this->render('@app/views/layouts/header', ['var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $var2])`

Comment: ok, but as you said, I didn't create any layouts inside my modules I wrote this line `$this->render('@app/views/layouts/header');` inside my module views directly in place of `include` file. Did you get my point?

Comment: Yeah its working fine but as per my question I didn't find the answer but the problem has been solved in other way like I use my default module's header i.e., Yii2's default controller,models,views. If you didn't understand what is default refer my question once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default view layouts. There is no need to create a views/layouts folder in your module.

Simply place all files in your frontend/views/layouts folder.